# How to retrieve value from json string in ionic

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework

please how can i retrieve the value of "src" from my array. im using ionic

here is my code in the ts

declaring the array to store the data

```
myaudio: any;
```

after retrieving the data into this.myaudio this is what i got

```
{
  "id": "12eabd38-a2b0-4a13-4732-e088998f7d21",
  "src": "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files/record114201920351.mp3",
  "_duration": -1,
  "_position": -1
}
```

now i want to get the value of "src" from this.myaudio into another variable

Comment: Something like this `var src = this.myaudio.src` ?

Comment: its not working please.

Comment: this.myaudio is an array or a object?

Comment: an object and i used JSON.stringify to get the data into this.myaudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used `JSON.stringify` to get the data into `this.myaudio`, you would have to `JSON.parse` it back to get a proper object you can access with the `.` notation.

Something like:

`this.myaudio = JSON.parse(this.myaudio);`

before you would be able to do `this.myaudio.src`.